# In Staged rollout when updated application will be displayed on play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We have done staged rollout for our application (application upgrade) but play store is still displaying previous application content. When page will also get updated?

Current staged rollout percentage is 1%

And how can we see, user count for whom application has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your staged rollout percentage is only 1% it might not cover you or the accounts you're using.

==> App update will be available to the percentage of users in your staged rollout, but **it may take time for the full group to receive the update**. You might be the user who isn't covered (by the rollout), so update notification will not fired to you.

It may be noticeable that:
**If you choose specific countries for your staged rollout, the upgrade will be limited to users with Google Play accounts in those locations.**

And yes there may be no criteria for choosing user base for staged rollout percentage.

Comment below if you have any doubt.

*Happy Coding...*

Answer (score 3):

`Playstore` decides the 1% of the users who will be seeing the update. You might or might not be one when u visit your app page.

You can see the no.of downloads on `App Releases - > RollOut section`

Comment: Its showing very less number of install events but as per current active users it should have been in thousands. Is there any min. limit for staging rollout percentage and 1% may not a valid number?

Comment: The Reflection of no.of installs on PlayStore will take some time... You can rely on Google Analytics Count on the particular app version if you have it in your app.